# hide css menu after selection not working with scrollbar

Tags: css, menu, scrollbar

I have a css menu that has been working fine.  Now I wanted to add a scroll bar to one of the menus when it get too long for the page.  The problem is that the hide menu on selection triggers when you attempt to click the mouse on the scroll bar.  Anyone have any idea on how I can fix this?

Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem...

https://jsfiddle.net/design523/xtk9bdL0/

The last two menu choices have the flyout with the scroll bars.
This is the new CSS I added that is creating the issues...

```
.addScroll {
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.addScroll:active {
  display:none;
}
```

Also, when you mouse down on the left half of either "10 codes" or "11 codes" an empty ul appears.  I would like to stop that from happening as well.  If anyone can see when I am going wrong I would really appreciate a little help.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand the problem why it is hiding when we click on the scrollbar

```
.cssmenu:active ul ul *{
  display:none;
}

.addScroll:active {
  display:none;
}
```

Above two css are actually creating this issue.
In the first what we are saying is when ul inside ul which is inside div, in our case, is active then hide it So when we click on scrollbar it is actually UL which becomes active when we click on scrollbar and this css get activated and set display as none which actually hides it.

And second css
    .addScroll.active is also same "addScroll" css is applied to child UL and same use-case i.e when child UL becomes active, hide it. And when we click on scrollbar it becomes active and it hides it.

HOPE THIS HELPS.

Comment: Yes, hiding the flyout menus when a selection is made was part of the original menu.  It was just when adding the scroll that all the problems poped up.  Can you maybe suggest another way to hide the flyout menus that won't trigger when the scroll is used.